# Is there a way to set an Ansible encrypted var and preserve all special characters?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-vault

I have a variable set in an encrypted ansible vault yaml file which has multiple special characters, including < { , " ' [ and %.

```
my_var: <X%X[X{,"<X'L
```

I need Ansible to take the variable as a raw string, but it's inserting a \ before the double-quote (") - at least that is what debug shows.

```
ok: [10.10.10.10] => {
    "my_var": "<X%X[X{,\"<X'L"
}
```

How can I get ansible to treat the variable as a raw string?

Comment: That double quote is being escaped as Ansible is showing you a JSON representation of your task as it's being processed. If you were to write that string into a file, that backslash would not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see depends on the [callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#callback-plugins). No quotation and/or escaping is needed

```yaml
shell> cat my_var.yml 
my_var: <X%X[X{,"<X'L
```

To test it, use *yaml* callback and iterate the string character by character

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - my_var.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for i in range(my_var|length) %}
          {{ i % 10 }}{% endfor %}

          {% for c in my_var %}
          {{ c }}{% endfor %}
```

gives (ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    0123456789012
    <X%X[X{,"<X'L
```

You'll get the same result when you encrypt the file

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt my_var.yml
Encryption successful
```

Comment: thanks Vladimir - this makes sense and is very helpful. The issue I was having didn't turn out to be the password at all, ansible was reading it correctly. I was trying to use the Ansible uri module and needed to use the  "force_basic_auth" setting.